# how to convert datatable value using array in Cake PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I am saving data on my database as '1' value. in 'post_id' table for a post id' 2'

When I call the value to view page(cakePHP) its shows like 1 because its save there as 1, i need to change it to `1=>'Movies' without modifying database values. using some array function.

Comment: explode(',' , $res['fieldname']);

Comment: probably some combination of `explode`, `array_map` and `implode` will work, but currently this question is too vague to answer

Comment: i just edited post please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function showCat($id){
switch($id){
case 1:
$value = 'Movies';
break;
case 2:
$value = 'Music';
break;
case 3:
$value = 'Sports';
break;
}
return $value;
}
$category = showCat($row['postto_id']);
echo $category;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if/else` condition in your view to check `$row['postto_id']` equal to `what id`.

Example

```
<div class="edu-desc-row-inner">
    <label>category:</label>
    <span>
    <?php
        if($row['postto_id'] == 1) echo 'Movies';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 2) echo 'Music';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 3) echo 'Sports';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 4) echo 'Nature';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 5) echo 'Science';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 6) echo 'Comedy';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 7) echo 'Tutorials';
        else if($row['postto_id'] == 8) echo 'Animation';
    ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @gopu0000 `$row` is example. You have to replace it with your `$result` variable.